# Values such that the equation is between 0 and 1

Tags: inequality, optimization

I have a question in my homework which I have tried to solve for days and think I am missing the very last few lines to complete and would really appreciate any help.

I got to the following equation:

$$
\frac{\left(1+2k\eta^{2}\beta^{2}\right)}{\alpha\eta k\left(1-\eta\beta^{2}\right)}=\frac{1}{\alpha\eta k\left(1-\eta\beta^{2}\right)}+\frac{2\eta\beta^{2}}{\alpha\left(1-\eta\beta^{2}\right)}
$$

Where $\alpha, \beta$ are positive real constants such that $\alpha <= \beta$.

I need to find positive values of $k, \eta$ such that the equation is between 0 and 1 (excluding).
Moreover $k = O(\frac{\beta^{2}}{\alpha^{2}})$.
And $\eta$ can also depend on $\beta$ and $\alpha$.

Would very much appreciate the help.
Thank you.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  A natural starting point might be to pik particular values for $\alpha, \beta$ (like maybe $(1,1)$) and solve the problem in that case.

Comment: The easy bit: to make the expression $>0$ note the signs of  $\left(1+2k\eta^{2}\beta^{2}\right)$ and $\alpha\eta k$ and $\left(1-\eta\beta^{2}\right)$.  That will tell you a constraint on $\eta$.  Then see if you can use the expression being $<1$ to put a constraint on $k$.  Then think about whether there are any more possible constraints